# Replace missing values that result from a pandas merge

Tags: python, pandas, merge

df1

```
|Invoice #  |Date        |Amount       
|12         |12/15/2015  |$10 
|13         |12/16/2015  |$11 
|14         |12/17/2015  |$12
```

df2

```
|Invoice #  |Date        |Amount
|12         |1/16/2016   |$10 
|14         |1/17/2016   |$12
```

Merged = df1.merge(df2,how = left, on = Invoice #)

```
|Invoice #  |Date         |Amount
|12         |12/15/2015   |$10
|NaN        |NaN          |NaN
|14         |1/17/2016    |$12
```

What I would like to do is take Invoice 13 that returned a NaN value in the merge and place it in a list.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify - do you mean you're doing the merge this way regardless, or do you just want a list of invoices that are not shared between df1 and df2?

Comment: I just want a list of invoices that are in df1 but not df2.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your merged result is not showing what actually happens with a left merge?

Here's what I get when I try to reproduce what I think you're trying to do (I'm using pandas version 0.19.0):

```
merged = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='Invoice #')
```

[image: merged]

Then you can mask by the missing values and get a dataframe containing those rows:

```
merged[merged['Amount_y'].isnull()]
```

[image: masked]

Or just create a column with the boolean flag:

```
merged['missing_from_df2'] = merged['Amount_y'].isnull()
```

To select things from the masked dataframe, treat it like any other dataframe, and index into one or more columns by listing them (note that if you want more than one, you have to do double brackets).

[image: select_columns]

You can save it to a new variable to make the syntax simpler if you want to do other things with it.

[image: masked_selection]

Comment: Is there anyway I can grab the corresponding invoice # and invoice date to go along with invoice 13

Comment: I mean the invoice amount and the invoice date.  I'd like to keep those grouped together.

Comment: Edited my answer to make it clearer what's actually happening here, so you can understand how to use the output. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

***method 1***
`pd.concat` + `drop_duplicates`

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(subset=['Invoice #'])
```

***method 2***
`combine_first`

```
df1.set_index('Invoice #').combine_first(df2.set_index('Invoice #')).reset_index()
```

***method 3***
`merge`

```
df1.merge(df2, on='Invoice #', suffixes=['', '_'], how='left')[df1.columns]
```

***method 4***
`join`

```
df1.join(df2.set_index('Invoice #'), on='Invoice #', rsuffix='_')[df1.columns]
```

---

***all produce***

[image]

---

***timing***
`pd.concat` + `drop_duplicates` is the fastest

[image]